# Installation of RT3290 wifi driver - make error

Tags: drivers, wireless, compiling, make, ralink

I'm trying to install the RT3290 wifi driver since wifi works on my laptop but sometimes randomly disconnects.

 I downloaded the driver here https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/nach-update-kein-wlan-mehr-433/2/#post-5561332 since the other sources are not available anymore.

 When i run the `make` command i get this output:

```
    make -C tools
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/tools'
    gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/tools'
   /home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/tools/bin2h
    cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/Makefile
    make -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-14-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux modules
    make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-14-generic'
      CC [M]  /home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o
    In file included from /home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/include/rtmp_os.h:42:0,
                 from /home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/include/rtmp_comm.h:56,
                 from /home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/include/rt_config.h:36,
                 from /home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:31:
/home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RTMPQueryInformation’:
/home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:3956:30: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
    DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_TRACE, ("sizeof UCHAR=%d, channel=%d \n", sizeof(UCHAR), p
                                  ^
/    home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/include/os/rt_linux.h:656:16: note: in definition of macro ‘DBGPRINT_RAW’
         printk Fmt;               \
                ^
    /home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../.. /sta/sta_cfg.c:3956:4: note: in expansion of macro ‘DBGPRINT’
        DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_TRACE, ("sizeof UCHAR=%d, channel=%d \n", sizeof(UCHAR), p
    ^
    /home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../..    /sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RTMPIoctlShow
/home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:4899:85: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
 intf(extra, size, "Driver version-%s, %s %s\n", STA_DRIVER_VERSION, __DATE__, _
                                                                     ^
/home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:4899:95: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
 , size, "Driver version-%s, %s %s\n", STA_DRIVER_VERSION, __DATE__, __TIME__ );
                                                                     ^
/home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RtmpIoctl_rt_private_get_statistics’:
/home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:7220:30: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘EEPROM_NIC_CONFIG3_STRUC {aka union _EEPROM_NIC_CINFIG3_STRUC}’ [-Wformat=]
 sprintf(extra+strlen(extra), "pAd->NicConfig3.field.CoexAnt == 0x%x\n\n",pAd->N
                              ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:294: recipe for target '/home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o] Error 1
Makefile:1524: recipe for target '_module_/home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/marco/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-14-generic'
Makefile:380: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2 </code>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error or succesfully installing the driver?
Thanks

Comment: Your driver is from 2012 and is certainly too old to use with current versions of the Ubuntu kernel. You'll have to keep looking for a newer driver... or somebody else will chime in with that info. You might look here https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=RT3290&type=

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a reason to build a different driver as the kernel uses the rt2800pci module.  However this module doesn't work well with wifi power management enabled, check results for `iwconfig`

You can disable wifi power management with

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Reboot